# Is my tape defective or there is another problem?

Tags: backup, tar, tape

I tried a backup with this line

```
 tar cvf - --format posix -b 1024 -X /home/user/altro/file.esclude /home/user | openssl aes-256-cbc -salt  -k "pass" | dd bs=40M of=/dev/st0
```

The total size of my backup is 1TB

The tape is LTO-5 1.5TB(3tb compressed)

After 15-30 minutes give me this error

```
[mar apr 11 20:40:07 2017] st 9:0:2:0: device_block, handle(0x0009)
[mar apr 11 20:40:07 2017] st 9:0:2:0: [st0] Error e0000 (driver bt 0x0, host bt 0xe).
[mar apr 11 20:40:09 2017] st 9:0:2:0: device_unblock and setting to running, handle(0x0009)
[mar apr 11 20:40:09 2017] st 9:0:2:0: [st0] Error 10000 (driver bt 0x0, host bt 0x1).
[mar apr 11 20:40:09 2017] st 9:0:2:0: [st0] Error on write filemark.
[mar apr 11 20:40:09 2017] st 9:0:2:0: [st0] Error 10000 (driver bt 0x0, host bt 0x1).
[mar apr 11 20:40:09 2017] mpt2sas_cm0: removing handle(0x0009), sas_addr(0x5001438000aa4a64)
[mar apr 11 20:40:09 2017] mpt2sas_cm0: removing : enclosure logical id(0x500605b0080ad4d0), slot(3)
[mar apr 11 20:40:13 2017] scsi 9:0:3:0: Sequential-Access HP       Ultrium 5-SCSI   Z6ED PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[mar apr 11 20:40:13 2017] scsi 9:0:3:0: SSP: handle(0x0009), sas_addr(0x5001438000aa4a64), phy(3), device_name(0x5001438000aa4a66)
[mar apr 11 20:40:13 2017] scsi 9:0:3:0: SSP: enclosure_logical_id(0x500605b0080ad4d0), slot(3)
[mar apr 11 20:40:13 2017] scsi 9:0:3:0: TLR Enabled
[mar apr 11 20:40:13 2017] st 9:0:3:0: Attached scsi tape st0
[mar apr 11 20:40:13 2017] st 9:0:3:0: st0: try direct i/o: yes (alignment 4 B)
```

Is something broken with hw or is a tar/dd error?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm seeing the same.

Comment: Yes and not, the "solution" was..defective hw,in my case the SAS cable, you have to try if possible with other hw(card,cables,etc).

Comment: Heh. Same here. Turned out to be a too-tightly-coiled fibrechannel cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the "solution" was defective hw,in my case the SAS cable.
After cable replacement works fine